# How to perform async compile and scaffold

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, roslyn, npgsql

ASP.NET 5 MVC Core application uses EF Core **Npgsql** runtime scaffold and **Roslyn** compile to different versions of EF Code `DbContext` assembly.

It takes 12 seconds to scaffold database. So `async` operations are preferred.
Scaffold interface does not have `async` versions:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding
{
    public interface IReverseEngineerScaffolder
    {
        SavedModelFiles Save([NotNullAttribute] ScaffoldedModel scaffoldedModel, [NotNullAttribute] string outputDir, bool overwriteFiles);
        ScaffoldedModel ScaffoldModel([NotNullAttribute] string connectionString, [NotNullAttribute] DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, [NotNullAttribute] ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, [NotNullAttribute] ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions);
    }
}
```

Roslyn `Create` method which compiles also don't have `async` version:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
{
    public sealed class CSharpCompilation : Compilation
    {
        public static CSharpCompilation Create(string? assemblyName, IEnumerable<SyntaxTree>? syntaxTrees = null, IEnumerable<MetadataReference>? references = null, CSharpCompilationOptions? options = null);
        public static CSharpCompilation CreateScriptCompilation(string assemblyName, SyntaxTree? syntaxTree = null, IEnumerable<MetadataReference>? references = null, CSharpCompilationOptions? options = null, CSharpCompilation? previousScrip
        ...
```

How to perform async scaffold and compile in EF Core?

Comment: The scaffold methods are not available Async, they are for design time, it seems very brittle to build a DbContext at runtime, and against the design and intention of these methods. The generated code should be reviewed and tested, not blindly compiled.

Comment: This is multi-company ERP application. Every company data is in separate database. Companies have added their own specific columns to tables. Different databases have different additional columns. Scaffolding DbContexts at runtime seems only pattern to handle this.

Comment: Generally agree with what @ErikEJ wrote above. However, if you really must scaffold at runtime, it's still a one-time operation, so whether it's executed synchronously or asynchronously shouldn't matter much. If scaffolding takes 12 seconds, it will take 12 seconds regardless of async.

Comment: Application servers 25 databases. Scaffold creates in-memory assembly for each. It application is re-started, 25 scaffolding processes triggered by web requests are running concurrently . This causes huge memory usage and thread pool starvation. Web application will be killed by Linux OOM, not possible to start it.